# VS860016: Could not find subject in the backing domain. This value came from the parameter 'originId'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm working with the Azure DevOps API and Microsoft Graph API. This is the issue:

I create an AAD (azure active directory) group, then, I create a new ADO (AzureDevOps) project in a XXX organization. Once the project is created I add the AAD group created at the beginning into the ADO project groups.

[image]

It works fine, but sometimes I get an error when I try to add the AAD group into the project permissions groups (the image above), the error is the same as the title: **"VS860016: Could not find subject in the backing domain. This value came from the parameter 'originId'."**

The first solution was creating a retry function, but it doesn't ever work, so, I'm trying to figure out was is the best approach to resolve the problem, I tried to find some information about this error, but not exists info regarding this.

Do you know the reason for the issue?
Creating a queue for this could work, but I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my Environment able to add the AAD group into the project permissions groups.

[image]

[image]

**Not Sure why you are getting the error, Even there is no document to troubleshoot for this Error. Would Suggest you please reach out to [*Azure Support Team*](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) for Solution and Root Cause.**